# Using a for loop to insert words with index appended in vim

Tags: vim

On more than one occasion I've had to insert some variation of a word into a list in python for example:

```
intf = ["eno1", "eno2", "eno3", "eno4", "eno5", "eno6", "eno7", "eno8", "eno9", "eno10"]
```

Is there perhaps an easy way to insert these words with a for loop?
I found this:
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/vim/commands/put
which is very close to what I want to do.
So for example I can do:

```
:for i in range(1,10) | put ='\"eno'.i.'\", ' | endfor
```

which gives me:

```
"eno1",
"eno2",
...
```

The only difference is that it inserts each word on a new line.
Is there perhaps a variation of this that inserts the words all on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Append all values to a variable first, then call [put](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aput).

```
:let a="" | for i in range(1,10) | let a.='"eof'.i.'", ' | endfor | put =a
```

2. To remove ending '`,` ', we can also [add](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#add%28%29) the values to a [list](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#List), and then call [join](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#join%28%29)

```
:let a=[] | for i in range(1,10) | call add(a,'"eof'.i.'"') | endfor | put =join(a, ', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply generate that list directly in your code?

```
intf = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    intf.append('eno' + str(i))
```

If you insist on doing it in Vim with Vim features:

```
intf = <C-r>=range(1,10)->map('"eno" . v:val')->string()<CR>
```

See `:help i_ctrl-r`, `:help "=`, `:help range()`, `:help map()`, `:help string()`, and `:help method`.

Comment: Thanks, the point was more to learn vim features. A similar example could pop up in json or any other data only format.

Comment: Well, my answer contains a pretty clean Vim-native solution.

Comment: Okay, I understand your solution a bit better now. It just needs to be adjusted a little. The "intf = " was part of the string literal, so I don't need to create a vim variable with that name. Perhaps the cleanest way to use your solution is to set a register with your function and then use put with that register. :let @i = "intf = <C-r>=range(1,10)->map('"eno" . v:val')->string()<CR>"
:put i
Btw, vim range seems to be inclusive.

Comment: Answer fixed. The idea is to directly type the provided snippet in insert mode. No need for intermediate registers or `:put`. You type `intf = <C-r>=...` in insert mode and you get exactly the desired outcome.